# Open WXpython menu in menubar programmatically

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to set up modified ALT+key accelerators in wxpython that will open the menus in the menubar, but without pressing the ALT key.  Hence, pressing the 'R' key in my example below would in theory open the Run menu, but everything that I have tried so far doesn't work.  (I have tried sending custom events to the menu item, to the menubar, etc.)  It seems that wx.Menu classes just do not have any sort of Popup or Show methods, which would otherwise be ideal.  There is of course PopupMenu, but that can't be used for menus that are in a menubar.  And menubar doesn't have any useful methods for popping up a menu that is part of it as far as I can tell

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)        

        self.make_menu_bar()

        # INSERT MAGIC CODE HERE TO OPEN THE RUN MENU WITHOUT CLICKING ON IT

    def make_menu_bar(self):
        self.menuRun = wx.Menu()
        self.menuRunGo = wx.MenuItem(self.menuRun, -1, "&Go", "", wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        self.menuRun.AppendItem(self.menuRunGo)

        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuBar.Append(self.menuRun, "&Run")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = wx.App()

    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT** Here is a snippet trying at this with accelerators

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)        

        self.make_menu_bar()

        accelEntries = []
        accelEntries.append((wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, ord("R"), self.menuRunId))
        accelTable  = wx.AcceleratorTable(accelEntries)
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accelTable)

    def make_menu_bar(self):
        self.menuRun = wx.Menu()
        self.menuRunGo = wx.MenuItem(self.menuRun, -1, "&Go", "", wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        self.menuRun.AppendItem(self.menuRunGo)

        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuRunId = self.menuBar.Append(self.menuRun, "&Run")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = wx.App()

    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I think you can just use http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.AcceleratorTable-class.html ... combined with `wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, ord('R')`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem - I don't want to fire the item run, I want to physically open the Run menu.  I'll edit my names to be more clear

Comment: perhaps if you gave it the same menu id as run menu ... maybe? Im not sure ...

Comment: But menu do not have Id - they are strictly containers, which is why you can't attach events to them

Comment: of coarse menu items have id... (and every menu must be accessible via a menu item) `my_id_i_want = self.menuBar.Append(self.menuRun, "&Run")`   I think

Comment: So what method of Menu/MenuBar/MenuItem can I call to make the menu popup?  Or is it not possible?

Comment: you bind my_id_i_want to the accelerator table entry  so that to the software R is indistinguishable from activating &Run (which presumably opens `menuRun`)

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you are getting at, let me try that.

Comment: I think this is what you had in mind?  Pressing the "R" key does not open the menu

Comment: I think the problem is that pressing alt (to get into the menu), and *then* pressing R is not the same thing as clicking on the Run menu

Comment: And btw, wx.Menu() items do not have Id.  self.menuRunId = self.menuBar.Append(self.menuRun, "&Run") gives self.menuRunId = True